# MongoDB with Laravel

Tags: apache-http-server, mongodb, computing-environment

### How to use `MongoDB` with `Laravel`

just needs the basic info.
How to configure *Mongo* on *Laravel*.
Environment requirements for **Mongo** for local development and for deployment on *shared hosting*.

Any tutorial or video series.
I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MongoDB Module for Laravel. Details can be found in the official Laravel module documentation. For MongoDB requirements see the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In this article you will know how to connect MongoDB with Laravel.
https://appdividend.com/2018/05/10/laravel-mongodb-crud-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Link-only answers are considered low quality. Please [edit] your answer and post the relevant part of the linked article *here*.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a fantastic database option for web applications because of its flexible schema structure and document architecture. It will quickly change to meet your changing demands.
Further, go through this [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-laravel-intergration) for more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).